# What will happen if get_object_or_404 finds many objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

As the title suggest, and if it doesn't raise 404, do I have any method to tell it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

> Note: As with get(), a MultipleObjectsReturned exception will be raised if more than one object is found.

edit:

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, something=1)
    except MyModel.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        # Maybe do something.
        raise Http404
```

Comment: So I need to have an exception handler for that? Do we have a function which will directly do that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to show 404 when multiple objects are returned? And under what circumstance do you expect more than one object to be returned? Can you give some context for your question?

Comment: Since I know it's going to be an incorrect situation if it's returning multiple objects, so I don't want the webpage to display such a page as a correct page. It should refuse the user from accessing that page I think.